# Checking dict keys to ensure a required key always exists, and that the dict has no other key names beyond a defined set of names

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict in python that follows this general format:

```
{'field': ['$.name'], 'group': 'name', 'function': 'some_function'}
```

I want to do some pre-check of the dict to ensure that 'field' always exists, and that no more keys exist beyond 'group' and 'function' which are both optional.

I know I can do this by using a long and untidy if statement, but I'm thinking there must be a cleaner way?

This is what I currently have:

```py
if (('field' in dict_name and len(dict_name.keys()) == 1) or 
    ('group' in dict_name and len(dict_name.keys()) == 2) or 
    ('function' in dict_name and len(dict_name.keys()) == 2) or 
    ('group' in dict_name and 'function' in dict_name and len(dict_name.keys()) == 3))
```

Essentially I'm first checking if 'field' exists as this is required. I'm then checking to see if it is the only key (which is fine) or if it is a key alongside 'group' and no others, or a key alongside 'function' and no others or a key alongside both 'group' and 'function' and no others.

Is there a tidier way of checking the keys supplied are only these 3 keys where two are optional?

Comment: I believe `{'group':'name','function':'func'}` would pass according to your second (and third) line.

Comment: You are correct, I hadn't noticed that as I knew there must be a better solution

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned you want to check, that

1. The set `{'field'}` is always contained in the set of your dict keys
2. The set of your dict keys is always contained in the set `{'field', 'group', 'function'}`

So just code it!

```
required_fields = {'field'}
allowed_fields = required_fields | {'group', 'function'}

d = {'field': 123}  # Set any value here

if required_fields <= d.keys() <= allowed_fields:
    print("Yes!")
else:
    print("No!")
```

This solution is scalable for any sets of required and allowed fields unless you have some special conditions (for example, mutually exclusive keys)

(thanks to @Duncan for a very elegant code reduction)

Comment: @Kolay.Ne I think you need to wrap `d.keys()` with `set` like this: `set(d.keys())`?

Comment: @CristianGutu That is not necessary, `dict.keys` returns a set-like view object.

Comment: @CristianGutu, yeah, this is how my code used to look before. Please, see the history of the editions of my answer to better understand what has changed and you will most likely understand why

Comment: (Correction of my previous comment) @CristianGutu There might actually be a good reason to do `set(d)` instead of `d.keys()`: efficiency. With the data in the code here, I got ~400 ns for `required_fields <= d.keys() <= allowed_fields` and ~330 ns for `required_fields <= set(d) <= allowed_fields`. And `d.keys()` took ~120 ns while `set(d)` took ~200 ns, so the version with `d.keys()` lost by 70 ns despite an 80 ns head start. I'm not sure exactly why (my previous reasoning turned out to be false).

Answer (score 17):

Yes, by converting your dict with a [**dataclass**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

```py
from typing import List, Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
     field: List[str]
     group: Optional[str] = None
     function: Optional[str] = None

result = MyDataclass(["$.name"], "name", "some_function")
# or, equivalently:
result = MyDataclass(field=["$.name"], group="name", function="some_function")

# access with result.field, result.group, result.function
```

To answer your question directly, you can write the following, and it will throw an exception when a field is missing from the input dictionary:

```py
dict_name = {'field': ['$.name'], 'group': 'name', 'function': 'some_function'}

MyDataclass(*dict_name)
```

Note that the above only works when your keys are strings, due to the use of the splat operator. (`*`)

Once converted to a dataclass, you can safely use it assured that it has the fields. This is less prone to errors, because it prevents you from mixing up a dict checked for missing parameters and an unchecked dict in different parts of your code. See [Parse, Don't Validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/) for a full explanation from a theoretical standpoint.

Dataclasses are the idiomatic way to do it in Python, similar to how objects (dictionaries) are the idiomatic way to do it in JavaScript. In addition, if you're using an IDE with mypy/pyre/PEP 484 support, you will get type hints on objects. **Thanks to the bidirectionality of PEP 484, that means if you create a dict with a missing field, and pass it to a function that converts it to a dataclass, the type checker may be able to check the error.**

You can convert a dataclass back to a dict using [**`dataclasses.asdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict).

Another option is namedtuple.

Comment: dataclasses are new in Python 3.7, for anyone wondering

Comment: @AaronF Most systems that we don't control ourselves today have at least Python 3.6. By the time you finish developing, most systems may already have Python 3.7.

Comment: Where I am we're stuck on RHEL 8 and Python 3.6, and we only finished the RHEL upgrade at the start of this year, so Python 3.7 is still quite a long way off for me :-(

Answer (score 9):

You can also use validation packages like `schema` https://pypi.org/project/schema/

```
from schema import Schema, And

my_schema = Schema({
    'field': And(str, len),
    'group': And(str, len),
    'function': And(str, len)
})

data = {
    'field': 'Hello',
    'group': 'This is a group',
    'function': 'some_function'
}

my_schema.validate(data)
```

Comment: How do you show that group and function are optional?

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ Use `Optional(...)` around them, eg. `Optional('function'): And(str, len)`, which makes having "function" optional, but when it is given, it must have a non-empty string as its value. Remember to import `Optional` too, from schema.

Answer (score 7):

[`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) returns a `set`-like [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) backed by the original data. You can take advantage of that to write a very concise test:

```
allowed = {'field', 'group', 'function'}

if 'field' in dict_name and dict_name.keys() <= allowed:
    ...
```

[`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) operator `<=` is equivalent to the `issubset` method.

You can use other set operations for the second condition:

```
allowed >= dict_name.keys()
```

```
len(dict_name.keys() | allowed) <= len(allowed)
```

```
not (dict_name.keys() - allowed)
```

Aside from readability, using operators is the only possibility when using a keys view in some cases. For example, the following fails to run:

```
dict_name.keys().issubset(allowed)
```

But the following works just fine:

```
dict_name.keys() <= allowed
```

You can do

```
allowed.issuperset(dict_name.keys())
```

But that's likely to wrap `dict_name.keys()` in an unnecessary `set` object. At the same time,

```
allowed >= dict_name.keys()
```

Will actually flip the operator and use the `<=` version because of how Python's [arithmetic operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ror__) resolve types.

Comment: Nice! I was playing around in the interpreter and got attribute error for `issubset` on `d.keys()`. Didn't know you can use the explicit operators though. Thanks for the education :)

Comment: The union may not be larger than three elements. Really 3 should be `len(allowed)`. That ensures that `dict_name.keys()` doesn't introduce any new elements

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `set` of allowed keys and check the dict's keys using the built-in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function:

```py
allowed_keys = {'field', 'group', 'function'}

if 'field' in d and all(key in allowed_keys for key in d):
    pass
```

This is actually equivalent to the `set`'s [`issubset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) method:

> Test whether every element in the set is in other.

So this can become even more compact by casting the dict's keys to a set and checking that they are a sub-set of the allowed keys:

```py
allowed_keys = {'field', 'group', 'function'}

if 'field' in d and set(d).issubset(allowed_keys):
    pass
```